# GRUB2 rescue boot into windows

Tags: grub, mbr, grub2

I had got 2 partitions on my harddrive:
1. win7;
2. Ubuntu 11.10;
As it can be predicted the GRUB loader was in the second partition and this partition was formated from ext4 to ntfs.
Now I get this message on load:
`error: no such partition`
`grub rescue>`
`grub rescue> ls`
`(hd0) (hd0,msdod5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`

Can i boot from GRUB's rescue to win7 without reinstalling Ubuntu to get GRUB?
I've tried:

```
grub> rootnoverify (hd0,0)
grub> makeactive
grub> chainloader +1
grub> boot
```

that i've read from Ubuntu's forum, but GRUB rescue returns:
`Unknown comman 'rootnoverify'` and so on for every command.